# Comic about academic career

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

Once I read a comics on web about a academic/professional career. In this comics the main character finish high school and start a college. His career is portraited like an epic journey fighting monsters, climbing moutains where the powers are the skills he gets along the college.

I appreciate if someone could tell me the name of this comics or a link.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this one. It was very much in the overblown sword+sorcery vein, with an impressively muscled guy standing atop a mountain with his shirt ripped open ... and then looking over and seeing an even bigger mountain